# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 429. Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 15

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот, который скидывает в чат изображения. После 20 изображений возникает ошибка `A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 429. Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 15`.

Попробовал

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['ph'])
def start_message(message):
    p = r"path_to_photos"
    mas = os.listdir(p)
    for i in mas:
        time.sleep(2)
        with open(p+i, 'rb') as f:
            bot.send_photo(str(chat_id), f)
```

Задержка в секунду или две не роляет, тем более, что в документации api написано `Макс. количество сообщений от бота в секунду — 30.` Если я делаю передышку в целую секунду. К тому же, сколько бы я не ставил задержку ошибка прилетает в любом случае ровно после 20 изображений.

Также советуют убрать `bot.remove_webhook()`, которого у меня, собственно и нет.

**Вопрос:**
Как обойти данную проблему?

Comment: [Также обратите внимание, что ваш бот не сможет отправлять более 20 сообщений в минуту в одну группу.](https://github.com/Telegram-Bot-FAQ/FAQ/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B-telegram-bot-api)

Comment: Спасибо, не видел, читал тут https://www.vamtlgrm.com/limity-sushhestvuyushhie-v-telegram/
Здесь не было.@ВасяВоронцов

Comment: а вопрос то в чем ?